# SQL Having Clause with multiple selected fields

Tags: sql, firebird, having

I have a SQL query such as the following:

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
FROM tablename
WHERE field1 = condition
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5
HAVING COUNT(field1) > 2
```

I expected the query to return only the results which have more than 2 rows in the resultset, however the query returns 0 zero.

Could anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  I need to keep my query selecting the fields it has been, but limit the results coming back to only those who have at least 2 rows.  If they only have 1, I don't want them included in my results.

Comment: Your query looks ok.  Perhaps the data isn't what you expect.

Comment: That actually depends on the dataset. I hope you realise that a `GROUP BY` on those fields also influences the `COUNT` in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I do realize that, which is why I'm not getting any results with a count greater than 2, but how can I only pull the users who have at least 2 rows matching my conditions without a group by?

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question with an example set of data and a more detailed description of what you want.

Comment: Wrong group order? The count is reset every time that `field5` is. Is that really what you want? Or do you want all the records as long as there are at least two records with that `field1`? Your query doesn't match your description, but I don't know which is off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect (although from my comment under the question I am not sure) that you want

```
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
FROM tablename 
WHERE field1 = condition
  AND field1 IN 
       (SELECT field1
        FROM tablename 
        GROUP BY 1
        HAVING COUNT(field1) >=2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

The where clause specifies that field1 has to be equal to condition.

count(field1) would essentially always be 1 (distinct values of field1 would be 1 and equal to condition).

That's why we always have 0 results since the count is never > 2.

Comment: That isn't true, you are assuming the group itself is unique, but for a set of `(<1, ...>, <1, ...>, <1, ...>)` where the `...` are the same values for field2 and up the count will be 3.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel count(field1) gives us count of distinct values for field1 which is 1. If this is changed to count(*), we would get the value as 3 per your example

Comment: No it wouldn't, that would be a `count(distinct field1)`. A `count(field)` simply counts the number of non-`NULL` values.